# Flutter Spacer vs Expanded

Tags: flutter, dart

What is the difference between `Expanded` and `Spacer` in Flutter? Why Flutter team added `Spacer` when we already have `Expanded`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Both `Spacer` and `Expanded` does the same job that is they fill up the remaining space in a widget like `Row` or `Column`. Before `Spacer`, we had to use

```
Expanded(child: Container())
```

And which is not very good. With `Spacer` we only have to use

```
Spacer()
```

So, using `Spacer`, we prevent us from writing more code and it also gives clear indication that we are just using it to fill up the remaining space. Both of them have same property of `flex` which defaults to `1`. The only difference is we don't have `child` property which makes sense. In fact `Spacer` is

```
Expanded(child: SizedBox.shrink());
```

---

**TL;DR**

```
Spacer()
```

is equivalent to

```
Expanded(child: Container())
```

Answer (score 12):

`Expanded` makes its *child* widget occupy space.

`Spacer` occupies space by itself.

If you look at the [implementation of `Spacer`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Spacer/build.html), you'll see that it's a wrapper around `Expanded` with a dummy child.

Is `Spacer` really necessary?  Probably not.  In an alternate universe, `Expanded` could have had an optional `child` argument instead.